# Partial derivative of piecewise continuous function

Tags: multivariable-calculus

For $t\geqslant 0$, put $$\varphi(x,t)=\begin{cases} 
x \quad (0\leqslant x\leqslant \sqrt{t}) \\
-x+2\sqrt{t} \quad (\sqrt{t}\leqslant x\leqslant 2\sqrt{t})\\
0 \quad(\text{otherwise})
\end{cases}$$ and put $\varphi(x,t)=-\varphi(x,|t|)$ if $t<0$.

How to prove that $D_2\varphi$ is not bounded on rectangle $[-1,1]\times [-a,a]$ for any $a>0$?

I can't evaluate $D_2\varphi$ explicitly. Can anyone give an answer to my question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: In the open set $\sqrt t < x < 2\sqrt t,$ you have a formula for $\varphi.$ So you can compute $D_2\varphi$ in this region. What is it?

Comment: I assume that you mean $\sqrt{t}<x<2\sqrt{t}$ then $(D_2\varphi)(x,t)=-1+\frac{1}{\sqrt{t}}$ and it's easy to see that $(D_2\varphi)(x,t)$ is not bounded in  neighborhood of $(0,0)$. Am I right?

Comment: I get $D_2\varphi = 1/\sqrt t$ in that region, but yes that's the idea.

Comment: Ohh sure! Thanks a lot for clear answer! +1